# Fixing a broken loop by changing exactly one character

Tags: c, puzzle, code-golf

I found [a site](http://www.gowrikumar.com/c/index.html) with some complicated C puzzles. Right now I'm dealing with this:

> The following is a piece of C code, whose intention was to print a minus sign 20 times. But you can notice that, it doesn't work.
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int main()
> {
>     int i;
>     int n = 20;
>     for( i = 0; i < n; i-- )
>         printf("-");
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Well fixing the above code is straight-forward. To make the problem interesting, you have to fix the above code, by changing exactly one character. There are three known solutions. See if you can get all those three.

I cannot figure out how to solve. I know that it can be fixed by changing `--` to `++`, but I can't figure out what single character to change to make it work.

Comment: I don't think this is "Too localized". While it may not be too useful in the real world, it's an interesting puzzle.

Comment: BTW, we're still missing one solution.

Comment: @Felix: Well, of course we now don't. I wrote that when we were.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
for( i = 0; -i < n; i-- )
        printf("-");
```

Here is a second one, thanks to Mark for helping me!

```
for( i = 0; i + n; i-- )
    printf("-");
```

And Mark also had the third one which is

```
for( i = 0; i < n; n-- )
    printf("-");
```

Comment: The second one would not work. You will get `-20, -21, -22,...`. But `i + n` should do it.

Comment: I think the second one needs `i+n` rather than `i-n` and you have it.  Nice.

Comment: You're right! I was sure it was related to this somehow but had abandoned hope a bit early in the process :P

Comment: That second one is awesome. Thank you. Thanks to Mark too, who apparently contributed a lot.

Answer (score 17):

Change `i--` to `n--` is another.

Okay - Gab made the fix, so I removed the other solution.  He wins!

Comment: @Gab:  Heh - I'm glad since you beat me by a minute with yours :)

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it includes all three solutions, but thanks a lot.

Comment: @Javier:  Good decision.  Gab thought of two before I did.  Fun problem.

Answer (score 7):

Third answer:

```
for( i = 0; i + n; i-- )  
    printf("-");
```

Thanks to Gab Royer for inspiration.

Explanation: Eventually , `i + n` will result in `-20 + 20 = 0` which is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    for( i = 0; i < n; n-- )  
    printf("-");
```

Changed i-- to n--

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of them, I think:

```
for( i = 0; i < n; n-- )
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison in the for loop can be any expression - you can negate i.

```
for (i = 0; -i < n ; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int n = 20;
    for( i = 0; i < n; n-- ) // Change i-- to n--
        printf("-");
    return 0;
}
```

Solution 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int n = 20;
    for( i = 0; -i < n; i-- ) // Compare to -i
        printf("-");
    return 0;
}
```

Haven't figured a third.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int n = -20; //make n negative
    for( i = 0; i < n; i-- ) 
        printf("-");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will never run, since 0 > 20. The condition in the loop will never be true.