# What's wrong with this C program

Tags: c, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help with C puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503376/help-with-c-puzzle)

The intention of the program was to print a minus sign 20 times, but it doesn't work.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
      int i;
      int n = 20;
      for( i = 0; i < n; i-- )
          printf("-");
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: it gives infinite minus sign...

Comment: @SurajRk It won't actually give infinite. It will eventually wraparound to being positive once you try to decrement when i = -2^31

Comment: Only *unsigned* arithmetic is defined to wrap by the standard; *signed* overflow is undefined behavior.  Therefore the compiler is allowed to emit a true infinite loop here.  Compare what gcc 4.4 does to this program with `-S -O2` and `-S -O2 -fwrapv`, for instance.

Comment: @Zack +1 Did not know that - very good to know

Comment: @Zack Excellent fact. +1

Comment: I saw this as an interview puzzle. Change the code by only changing/inserting/deleting _exactly one_ character to make it print 20 times.

Comment: @Zack:  In practice, most general-purpose computer systems will wrap around.  You can't count on it.  An infinite loop is entirely fine according to the Standard, as is any other behavior whatsoever.

Answer (score 26):

This is a classic puzzle!

The way I saw it was

"You can only change/insert/delete one character in the code to make the - print 20 times".

Some answers are (if I remember them correctly)

1)

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
  int main() 
  { 
      int i; 
      int n = 20; 
      for( i = 0; -i < n; i-- ) 
          printf("-"); 
      return 0; 
  }
```

Here you change the `i < n` to `-i < n`

2)

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
  int main() 
  { 
      int i; 
      int n = 20; 
      for( i = 0; i < n; n-- ) 
          printf("-"); 
      return 0; 
  }
```

Here you change the `i--` to `n--`

3)

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
  int main() 
  { 
      int i; 
      int n = 20; 
      for( i = 0; i + n; i-- ) 
          printf("-"); 
      return 0; 
  }
```

You change the `i < n` to `i+n`.

For a challenge, try changing/inserting/deleting one character to make it print the - *21* times. (Don't read the comments to this answer if you want to try it!)

Comment: +1 for making this a puzzle. Well thought answer.

Comment: The challenge was fun ;) Glad I didn't look at the comments before trying to answer it though.

Answer (score 24):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
      int i;
      int n = 20;
      for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
          printf("-");
      return 0;
  }
```

You had `--` instead of `++`

Comment: Yup, that loop will run forever because `i` starts at `0` and keeps getting smaller. It will never be larger than *n* so the loop's exit condition will never be reached.

Comment: Surely it will be larger than n when the integer wraps around? The loop will just run for a little longer than intended is all.

Answer (score 10):

Replace i-- with i++.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main() { 
  int i; 
  int n = 20; 
  for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("-"); 
  return 0; 
}
```

You had decrement instead of increment.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the

```
i--
```

to

```
i++
```

You have the loop to print out a "-" for as long as "i" is less than 20.
After every loop you reduce the value of i by 1, it will continue to print
for a very long time. Changing the final part of the for loop to "i++" means it will perform one iteration each loop and stop once the twentieth iteration finished.

Answer (score 2):

Change i-- to i++.
i-- decrements the value which at start is 0 and with subsequent reductions won't ever reach 20 (or +20).

Answer (score 1):

the i-- needs to be i++

you could also do

```
 int n = -20;
  for( i = 0; i > n; i-- )
```

but that is bad coding practice

Comment: Why suggest an answer that's bad coding practice?

Comment: because in other situations you do want to decrement your counter. in this case decrementing the counter doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jamie Creativity ;) One can learn even from something that shouldn't be done a particular way.

Comment: Creativity has its places - suggesting a course of action to someone who is clearly a beginner in c is not one of them. Also, I agree that decrementing counters is occasionally more useful - so suggest it _when_ it is more useful. Again, this is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do with this problem???
Here you are trying to decrement the value of a variable..a variable whose value will never reach the condition (i<20) you have provided... hence it will keep on printing '-' until what jamie wong specified, i.e. `i= -2^31`. It will become +ve. I just tried this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int n = 20;
    for( i = 0; i < n; i-- )
        printf("-");
    return 0;
}
```

According to the question you asked, `i` should be incremented, i.e. `i++` instead of `i--`.

@jamie wong: thanx man..learnt a new thing about tht a wraparound....

Answer (score -1):

You'll print no dashes.  You can either go with Jaime Wong's solution or do this:

`for (i = n; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: You'll print SO MANY dashes. Also, that's kind of a terrible way to do it. Very much not the norm, and is pointlessly slightly obscure.

Comment: That won't print no dashes, as everyone else explained.
Also, you spelled my name wrong.

Comment: Whoops, you're right.  Sorry about that, on both counts.