# Interview - C++ (How to output five "20")

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixing a broken loop by changing exactly one character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503376/fixing-a-broken-loop-by-changing-exactly-one-character)

This is an interview question. I have the code below. How to output five "20" by just changing or adding *one* character of the code?

I can think of one solution, which is "-i < n". Is there any other solutions?

```
    int i , n = 5;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i--)
    {
        cout << "20" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: That probably is the only solution. Although, I can think of a few different solutions if you're allowed to change *two* characters

Comment: There are other two solutions as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: I think this is a trick question. In my opinion, it's immensely stupid to request a solution by changing one character. If you asked me that question, my reply without even considering to think about a solution for a second would be "What's the hindrance to writing a proper loop, and intuitive code?".